# gin checks array of json objects

Tags: go, go-gin

go version:1.18

request params

```json
{
    "questions_batch_id": "1",
    "answer_list": [
        {
            "questions_ids": "1",
            "answer": [
                "2222","3333"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

validate code:

```golang
type Answer struct {
    QuestionsID string   `json:"questions_id" binding:"required"`
    Answer      []string `json:"answer" binding:"required"`
}

type AnswerQuestionParams struct {
    QuestionBatchId string    `json:"questions_batch_id" binding:"required"`
    AnswerList      []*Answer `json:"answer_list" binding:"required"`
    UserId          string    `json:"user_id" binding:"-"`
    UserType        string    `json:"user_type" binding:"-"`
}
```

I was used `required,dive` got an error :`reflect: call of reflect.Value.Interface on zero Value`

I hope when the questions_id in the answer_list does not exist, the verification fails